# How to update SCSS in an existing angular project?

Tags: angular, sass

I'm trying to update the version of SCSS in my angular project. When creating the project I chose scss in the angular cli, so I'm already using SCSS. But now I have to import a spacing library that requires SCSS option "slash as division" that was introduced in [this version](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/slash-div) of SCSS.

I tried this:

```
npm update -g sass
-> C:\Program Files\nodejs\sass -> C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\sass\sass.js
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.2 (node_modules\sass\node_mod
ules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: want
ed {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ sass@1.43.4
added 15 packages from 18 contributors in 1.495s
```

but the import still fails with this warning:

```
    Error: ./src/styles.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined function.
  ╷
6 │     @return math.div($number, ($number * 0 + 1));
  │             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  node_modules\@library-I-want-to-use\utilities\dist\scss\helper\_internal.scss 6:13      -
-p-strip-unit()
  node_modules\@library-I-want-to-use\utilities\dist\scss\helper\_helper.scss 12:10       p
-px-to-rem()
  node_modules\@library-I-want-to-use\utilities\dist\scss\variables\_font.scss 11:18      @
import
  node_modules\@library-I-want-to-use\utilities\dist\scss\functions\_typography.scss 1:9  @
import
  node_modules\@library-I-want-to-use\utilities\dist\scss\functions\_index.scss 3:9       @
import
  node_modules\@library-I-want-to-use\utilities\dist\scss\_index.scss 1:9                 @
import
  node_modules\@library-I-want-to-use\utilities\scss.scss 1:9                             @
import
  src\styles.scss 1:9
```

Answer (score 0):

Sass is part of Angular, so updating Angular to Angular 12 did the trick.